# Passing DataTable from controller to PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a way to pass a `DataTable` to the `PartialView` using a `Controller` Action. Or if you know better way, I'm open to suggestions.

Controller:

```
public DataTable GetDailyOutput()
{
    Graph g = repository.Graphs.Where(p => p.GraphID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
    DataTable dt = repository.GetGraphData(g.StoredProc);
    return dt;
}
```

View:

```
<div id="dvCategoryResults">
    @{Html.Partial("_GetDailyOutput", Html.Action("GetDailyOutput", "Graph"));}
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>
                    @col.ColumnName
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
       {
           <tr>
               @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
               {
                    <td>
                        @row[col.ColumnName]
                    </td>
               }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My next step would be to update the table with an Ajax call and refresh the `PartialView`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will probably need to use AJAX for this. You can put the code below in an event handler, such as the handler for a button click.

**AJAX example using [JQuery `$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):**

```
$.post('@Url.Content("~/Graph/_GetDailyOutput")', function( data ) {
    $( "#dvCategoryResults" ).html( data );
});
```

**Controller action:**

```
public PartialViewResult _GetDailyOutput()
{
    Graph g = repository.Graphs.Where(p => p.GraphID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
    DataTable dt = repository.GetGraphData(g.StoredProc);
    return PartialView(dt);
}
```

If you prefer, you can render the partial view initially without using JavaScript by doing

```
<div id="dvCategoryResults">
        @Html.Action("_GetDailyOutput", "Graph")
</div>
```

Comment: PartialView is not recognized by intellisense, are you mean PartialViewResult? That returns me an error: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: What is it exactly that's throwing this error? `@Html.Action`?

Comment: Yes @Html.Action, But it _GetDailyOutput is completed

Comment: Ah. In that case, call your ajax when the page loads instead.

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood you, I didn't use Ajax yet, only the Action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72414/discussion-between-sippy-and-whistler).